# How to format timer in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to format a timer in Angular, so bellow 10, 9 becomes 09, 8 - 08, etc. till 0 - 00.

I didn't find a built-in pipe. How can I achieve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: can you write the format which you are looking for?

Comment: Are you trying to format date value or number value to string?

Answer (score 1):

> import built-in function `formatDate`

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

**12-Hours format**

```
this.currentDateTime = formatDate(responseData.CreatedDateTime, 'MMM, dd yyyy hh:mm:ss aa', 'en-US');
```

**24-Hours format**

```
this.currentDateTime = formatDate(responseData.CreatedDateTime, 'MMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'en-US');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version, showing the time in seconds:

```
Component:

private timer;
private counter: Date;

ngOnInit() {
  this.timer = Observable.timer(0,1000)
    .subscribe(t => {
      this.counter = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0);
      this.counter.setSeconds(t);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.timer.unsubscribe();
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="client-time">
  <span>Client time</span><br/>
  <strong>{{counter | date:'HH:mm:ss'}} seconds</strong>    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers - my question was however not about dates - just if I create a simple timer, how to add 0 when the timer is under 10 - like, instead of 10, 9, 8, etc. - 10, 09 , 08, 07, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pipes  as follows

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```

> {{datevar | date: 'short'}}

- 'short': equivalent to 'M/d/yy, h:mm a' (6/15/15, 9:03 AM).
- 'medium': equivalent to 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a' (Jun 15, 2015, 9:03:01
  AM).
- 'long': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a z' (June 15, 2015 at
  9:03:01 AM GMT+1).
- 'full': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a zzzz' (Monday, June
  15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).
- 'shortDate': equivalent to 'M/d/yy' (6/15/15).
- 'mediumDate': equivalent to 'MMM d, y' (Jun 15, 2015).
- 'longDate': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y' (June 15, 2015).
- 'fullDate': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y' (Monday, June 15, 2015).
- 'shortTime': equivalent to 'h:mm a' (9:03 AM).
- 'mediumTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a' (9:03:01 AM).
- 'longTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a z' (9:03:01 AM GMT+1).
- 'fullTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a zzzz' (9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Angular Date Pipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) like this:

```
<div>{{ today | date : 'EEEE, MMMM d, hh:mm:ss a' }}</div>
```

TS:

```
today: Date = new Date(2020,3,5,10,9,8);
```

Output:

> Sunday, April 5, 10:09:08 AM

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-format-pipe-6kyqo5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

here `hh, mm, ss` will make sure you have two digits even when value is less than 10

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers - my question was however not about dates - just if I create a simple timer, how to add 0 when the timer is under 10 - like, instead of 10, 9, 8, etc. - 10, 09 , 08, 07, etc ...